# Unable to download a csv file from the URL with python script

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am accessing a url with username and password to download a csv and save the file with today's date nad time, there is only one download link on the page.

Is there any way I can achieve this task via python

I am using this below script I see the print output. but how can I download the the <kbd>download csv</kbd> button on the web-page. Normally when I click on the download csv button it asking me to save the file.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://url.com'
login_data = dict(login='user@example.com', password='password-g')
session = requests.session()

link = 'https://url.com'

r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all('a', {'class': "app-btn-down"}):
    print(re.search('http://.*\b_file', i.get('href')).group(0)) # the CSV file name is b_file
    print ("r.text")
```

As I'm new to python, so please forgive me for my bad explanation.

Comment: You have to submit the `login_data`

Comment: I have mentioned `login_data` on the 6 Line

Comment: You have defined `login_data` il line 6 but you don't submit it. Also it seems that you should request the `"app-btn-down"` link. If you can share the real `url` i might be able to help more.

Comment: The actual link is intranet link. So even if i share the link it will not get open.

Comment: Any working sample will do. There is a link which needs a login credential, and there is only one download button which is having a different link. when clicked on that link its asking me to save location.

Comment: Well, as i mentioned previously you hve to login first: `session.post(url, data=login_data)`. Then use `session` to get the link: `r = session.get(link)`. Finally get the file: `csv_file = session.get(i.get('href')).text`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156424/discussion-between-mongrel-and-t-m-adam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly pseudocode since i don't know the html data, but i think you'll get the idea.

First you have to submit your data to get the necessary cookies in your session (you can check the cookies with `s.cookies`). Keep in mind that there may be more fields that you have  to submit other than `login` and `password`.  Use this session for all your requests.

Then you can get the csv link with `bs4` assuming it's not generated by js, otherwise you may have to use `selenium`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import gmtime, strftime
import os

s = requests.session()
url = 'https://url.com'
login_data = dict(login='user@example.com', password='password-g')
s.post(url, data=login_data)

link = 'https://url.com'
r = s.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

csv_link = soup.find('a', {'class':'app-btn-down', 'href':lambda h:'b_file' in h})['href']
csv_file = s.get(csv_link).text
```

Finally you can get the date and time with `gmtime`, and use `strftime` to format it.

```
date_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
path = os.path.join('/some/dir', date_time)
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(csv_file)
```